# Too many failed attempts to build model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am currently using kerastuner ( 1.0.0) to fine-tune hyperparamteters in a CNN and it keeps displaying the error 'Too many failed attempts to build model.'. I have tried all other availabel solutions including those on this stackoverflow but none of them works. Does my model have too many parameters to tune?

````
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import fashion_mnist
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Dropout, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.initializers import LecunNormal
!pip install keras-tuner==1.0.0
from kerastuner.tuners import RandomSearch
from kerastuner import HyperModel
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)
x_test = x_test.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)

class MCDropout(tf.keras.layers.Dropout): 
  def call(self, inputs): 
    return super().call(inputs, training=True)

NUM_CLASSES = 10
KERNEL_SIZE = (3, 3)

class CNNHyperModel(HyperModel):
    def __init__(self,  num_classes, kernel_size):
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.kernel_size = kernel_size

    def build_model(self, hp):
        model = keras.Sequential()
        model.add(Conv2D(ilters=hp.Choice('input_units', values=[32, 16], default=16),
                kernel_size=(self.kernel_size),
                activation='selu',
                kernel_intializer = LecunNormal,
                input_shape=x_train.shape[1:]))
        model.add(MCDropout(rate=hp.Float('dropout_0',min_value=0.0,max_value=0.2,default=0.1,step=0.1)))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
        
        for i in range(hp.Choice('n_filters', 1, 4)): 
          model.add(Conv2D(hp.Choice(f'num_filters_{i}', values=[32, 16, 64], default=32), 
                kernel_size=(self.kernel_size),
                activation='selu', 
                kernel_intializer = LecunNormal))
          model.add(MCDropout(hp.Float(f'dropout_{i}',min_value=0.0,max_value=0.2,default=0.1,step=0.1)))
          model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
      
        model.add(Flatten())
        
        model.add(Dense(units=hp.Choice('units',values = [128, 256, 512, 1024], defaults = 512),activation='selu'))
        model.add(MCDropout(rate=hp.Float('dropout_5',min_value=0.3,max_value=0.7,default=0.4,step=0.1)))
        model.add(Dense(self.num_classes, activation='softmax'))

        model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Nadam(hp.Choice('learning_rate',
                      values=[1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4])),
            loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
            metrics=['accuracy'])
        return model

hypermodel = CNNHyperModel(num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, kernel_size = KERNEL_SIZE)
SEED = 1
tuner = RandomSearch(
    hypermodel,
    objective='val_accuracy',
    max_trials = 1, 
    executions_per_trial = 1
    )
tuner.search(x=x_train, 
             y=y_train, 
             epochs=1, 
             batch_size=64, 
             validation_data =(x_test, y_test))```
````

I RUN THIS CODE AND IT KEEP DISPLAYING TOO MANY FAILED ATTEMPTS TO BUILD MODELS. (BTW I AM WRITING THIS ON GG COLAB.)

IS THERE ANYWAY TO FIX IT?

Comment: Please refrain from using capital letters to emphasize the question (try italics or bold), as it makes the question unreadable. Also, please post the error you are getting in the body of the question in a separate code block

Comment: ok thanks for your advice, let me post the error